# iOS8 Size Classes: Compact width and regular height is not iPhone portrait

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8, size-classes

This image shows, that regular height and compact width is an iPhone in portrait. 
[image]

The settings in the xib shows wC and hR which translates to width is compact and height is regular. Practically, these settings are not applied in an app build with Xcode 6 Beta 7. It takes the Any:Any aka constant setting. Is this a bug or am I wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Too Late but I Hope it will help someone

1. iPad Portrait:  Regular/(Vertical Size Class)   Regular/(Horizontal Size Class)
2. iPad Landscape:     Regular/(Vertical Size Class)   Regular/(Horizontal Size Class)
3. iPhone:     Regular/(Vertical Size Class)   Compact/(Horizontal Size Class)
4. iPhone Landscape:   Compact/(Vertical Size Class)   Compact/(Horizontal Size Class)
5. iPhone 6 Plus Landscape:    Compact/(Vertical Size Class)   Regular/(Horizontal Size Class)

[For more](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/)

**UPDATE:**
Just found another link [size class example link](http://www.sizeclasses.com/?utm_source=ios%20dev%20tools&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=ios%20dev%20tools&at=11lvzs&ct=ios%20dev%20tools#fullscreen)